# How to fix Google Analytics "analytics.js" net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The relevant line of the Google script is:

```
(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

I am running this particular file locally (as in, I double-click "index.html" on Windows Explorer and it opens in Chrome.

After about a minute of trying to load this file it fails with `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` reported in the Developer Console.

I understand why this is happening, it is trying to load this as a local file.  If I do this it works just fine:

```
(window,document,'script','www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

In other words, I eliminated the `//`.  This would work just as well:

```
(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Is going explicitly doing it this way to only track real websites?

If so, how are you dealing with this issue for local development?

I do run a VM with Ubuntu server for local development of more elaborate sites.  In this case I was working on a single file landing page that I knocked out quickly and wanted to just test just as easily but ran into the browser hanging waiting for `analytics.js`

Is it safe to remove the `//` or add `http:` in general terms.  I don't generally like to modify Google code unless I fully understand why they are doing things in a specific way and what the consequences of my actions might be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of viewing the file locally, run it through a local webserver. Two easy options are

1. XAMPP: http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp
2. Uniform Server: http://www.uniformserver.com/

Both require no installation. If you have [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) or [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/), you can also run it through Cassini or IISExpress.

Comment: Thanks.  I run a VM with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as my development server.  So, I would not normally have this issue.  This one got me because I got lazy and simply wanted to work on this simple isolated html file directly off the Windows file system.  Now I am wondering about whether or not it would be advisable to edit the Google URL as I indicated in my question on files that deploy to real production servers.  I can't think of one negative consequence.

Comment: Specifically, don't change it to `http://`; you want to use `https://` if the site itself is running under SSL. Using `//` lets the script 'inherit' the same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you are using a VPN(Virtual private network) which analytics blocks. Try loading https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
If id does not work try disabling the VPN and try again.

Or as someone else [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983316/get-https-www-google-analytics-com-analytics-js-neterr-connection-refused) it could be that your AdBlock is blocking it.